# Google Maps API v3 with custom map image - markers repeating horizontally

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have custom map image tiles in use with Google Maps API v3. When I place a marker on the map, the marker repeats horizontally as if the map repeated as well. Here is an image of what is happening: http://puu.sh/vN7b

How can this be fixed? I don't want to limit the map bounds to fix this.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to prevent markers from repeating horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1/ In function convertCoords(nx,ny,map) you do:

```
x = (((nx + (6000 / 2)) / 6000) * cor1)
y = ((((ny * -1) + (6000 / 2)) / 6000) * cor2)
```

Shouldn't that be something like:

```
x = (((nx + (6000 / 2)) / 6000) * cor1.lat());
y = ((((ny * -1) + (6000 / 2)) / 6000) * cor2.lng())
```

In my tests, as it is, x and y are `NaN`.

2/ Your map is at zoom level 1. Isn't that expected if you don't limit the bounds of the map?

Comment: Re (2): It appears it is in Version 3. In Version 2 of the API it was possible to inhibit the horizontal repeat (it was an attribute of the `projection` class).